# Every 150 spent gets a 20 credit, but if 160 is spent, no credit is applied

Tags: php

I'm writing a customer loyalty system.  I have a page where I type in the user's customer ID and the amount they spent.  I want to write it to where every $150 they spend, they get a $20 credit they can use, but I ran into a bump.

Let's say the user's current balance is $140.  They need to spend another $10 to get the credit applied.  However, if they spend $20, their balance becomes $160 and no credit is applied.

Any suggestions?

```
$transac['newBalance'] = $row['balance'] + $transac['amount'];

    if ($transac['newBalance']%150 == 0 ) {
        // +20 to credit
        $transac['newCredit'] = $row['credit'] + 20;
        $query = "UPDATE customers SET credit='" . $transac['newCredit'] . "' WHERE userid = '" . $transac['username'] . "'";
        if (!mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)) {
            die("Query Error (" . $query . "): " . mysqli_error($mysqli));
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `%` is in the majority of programming (PHP is a scripting language, but still) languages the **modulo operator**, which is closely related to division. Read up more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to consider whether the new spending put the total balance past a new multiple of $150.

```
$transac['newBalance'] = $row['balance'] + $transac['amount'];
$oldMultiple = floor($row['balance']/150); //Previous multiple of 150
$newMultiple = floor($transac['newBalance']/150); //Current multiple of 150
$difference=$newMultiple-$oldMultiple; //Are they different?

if ( $difference>0 ) {
    // +20 to credit for each multiple of $150 that was passed
    $transac['newCredit'] = $row['credit'] + 20 * $difference;
    $query = "UPDATE customers SET credit='" . $transac['newCredit'] . "' WHERE userid = '" . $transac['username'] . "'";
    if (!mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)) {
        die("Query Error (" . $query . "): " . mysqli_error($mysqli));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`%` is the wrong operator here. You want simple division. You can figure out how many credits of $20 they have just by dividing their total expenditure by 150 and rounding down.

For example, if somebody has spent $140, `140 / 150`, rounded down, is 0.

If somebody has spent $310, `310 / 150` is 2.06; rounded down, you get 2, so they have 2 credits of $20, or (`2 * 20`) $40.

You can use PHP's `floor` for the round-down part:

```
$spent = 140.0;

$credits = floor($spent / 150.0) * 20; # 0

$spent = 310.0;

$credits = floor($spent / 150.0) * 20; # 40
```

Comment: Unless balance is reset each time, the customer will keep getting credits for the same purchases over and over.